# Would a projectile keep going forever in empty space?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, projectile

Would a projectile fired in space and assuming there were no stars or planets in the way, would the projectile continue on to infinity, since the x-component of the projectile's velocity never changes from it's original?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the projectile had enough velocity to escape the gravitational potential of the "projector" (system that fired it). And assuming that space-time is otherwise basically flat.

Then, Yes.

Comment: So wait, the projectile itself has a gravitational pull?

Comment: @LordZardeck: I assumed that the projectile was fired by something else and the two will be gravitationally attracted.

Comment: Wow, didn't know that. cool.